# Nested route in React Router reloads the entire page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to setup nesting in the react router. I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import DefaultSwitch from './components/DefaultSwitch/DefaultSwitch';
import './scss/App.scss';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <DefaultSwitch />
    );
};
export default App;
```

With `DefaultSwitch` defined as:

```
const DefaultSwitch = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
            <Route exact path='/logout' component={Logout} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

Inside the `Dashboard` I have the following:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <MyNavbar />
            <DashboardSwitch />
        </div>
    );
};
```

And finally `DashboardSwitch` as:

```
const DashboardSwitch = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Home} />
            <Route exact path='/dashboard/home' component={Home} />
            <Route exact path='/dashboard/bonuses' component={Bonuses} />
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

Routing appears to work and the correct components are loaded, however I have noticed that if for example I am at `/dashboard` and then navigate to `/dashboard/bonuses` the entire page is reloading including the `MyNavbar` component. I want the navbar to remain static and only the content below it to reload as I have defined in the `Dashboard` component.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a layout common to all components or something like this to avoid lose MyNavbar, for example:

```
const App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Route exact path='/logout' component={Logout} />
                <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/dashboard/home' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/dashboard/bonuses' component={Bonuses} />
            </Switch>
        </Layout>
    </BrowserRouter>
)

const Layout = ({ children }) => (
    <div>
        {children}
        <MyNavbar />
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Won't this layout show the `MyNavbar` on all screens? It should only show on the `dashboard` routes.

Comment: Of course, you have to code your own solution using this short example.